# Best practice for mapping variables with translations

Tags: android, performance, optimization, internationalization

I have a Table with lots of rows which should be translated. Most of the values are integers so the values don't need to be translated.

However my data comes from a JSON structure where the data are stored normal in key value pairs. E.g.:

```
{
  "age":24,
  "hair-color":"black",
  "weight":42,
  "height":123,
  // ...
}
```

So far I have a strings.xml which looks like this:

```
<resources>
  <string name="meta_age">Alter</string>
  <string name="meta_hair_color">Haarfarbe</string>
  <string name="meta_weight">Gewicht</string>
  <string name="meta_height">Körpergröße</string>
  <!-- ... -->
</resources>
```

This data are visualisated in a list view with a custom ArrayAdapter. This works fine however I'm not sure what is the best way for mapping the key value pairs with its translations.

I have now this code here:

```
public static final int[] fields = new int[] {R.string.meta_age, R.string.meta_hair_color, R.string.meta_weight, R.string.meta_height, /* ... */;
```

For the building the UI the strings need to be mapped to the *keys* so far this is done with this messy code:

```
List<Integer> fieldIndex = new ArrayList<Integer>(fields.length);
for(int i : fields) {
    fieldIndex.add(i);
}
translation = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
translation.put("age", fieldIndex.indexOf(R.string.meta_age));
translation.put("hair-color", fieldIndex.indexOf(R.string.meta_hair_color));
translation.put("weight", fieldIndex.indexOf(R.string.meta_weight));
translation.put("height", fieldIndex.indexOf(R.string.meta_height));
```

The next step is that I now know the target index for the json field and put them together with the fields list of string ids. But I think that this code is not very performant. How can I write that better?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds indeed a bit complicated. Why not just have dictionary with all possible translations in a key / translation kinda way.
Most translation frameworks work like this too.

Comment: Well that stuff with R.string is typically for Android. I'm just not sure if my mappings makes sense...

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier if you would have a key in our translation resource file that you could map in one go with your translations? E.g. instead of using meta_hair_color, use meta_hair-color like in the json? Then you could get the translation strings based on their name directly. No?

Comment: The minus sign is not allowed in translation variables and the json comes from a *external* API. Another reason for that fields array is that I don't want to use the order of the JSON string.